# How to enable emoji support in Ionic Apps for Android

Tags: ionic-framework, emoji

I am building an ionic app for Android, and would like to use emojis in it, is there any way to invoke native keyboard emojis using java script or anything? or Is there any keyboard plugin for that(I already installed ionic keyboard plugin)? Or can anyone just guide me on how can I do that so that I can work in that direction? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On Android 6.0.1 Marshmallow, you can bring the emojis by long-pressing the "enter" key of the keyboard.